# Guardar resultado de busqueda en diferentes archivos .json

Tags: python, json, mongodb, datatables, pymongo

tengo una duda, me gustaria guardar el resultado de una consulta a una base de mongo en varios .json para cargarlos a una coleccion distinta.
El codigo que tengo actualmente guarda el resultado en un solo .json. Tenia la idea que tal vez con un bucle **for** que haga una itereacion con los cada resultado, puede usar el metodo `with open()` y así ir creando los .json pero no me funcionó.

Mucho agradeceria si me pueden dar una mano con este problemita que tengo.

````
       entry['_id'] = str(entry['_id'])

    for entry in Result:
        Num = 0
        Num = Num +1
        cadena =str(Num)
        entry['_id'] = str(entry['_id'])
        with open('email'+cadena+'.json', 'w') as file:
            for elementos in entry:
                json.dump(entry, file) ```
````

Comment: No olvides cerrar el archivo después de haber escrito en el, esto te evita problemas y controlas el consumo de memoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicializas `Num = 0` en cada iteración del ciclo. Cuando llega a la linea `with open()`, cadena siempre tiene `'1'`, por lo que siempre abre el archivo `email1.json`.

Si quieres generar distintos archivos, inicializa `Num` antes de iniciar el ciclo, lo cual funcionará siempre que haya más de un elemento en `Result`.

```python
Num = 0
for entry in Result:
    Num += 1
    bla, bla, bla
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @jachguate estaba iniciando el contador dentro del ciclo.
Gracias por echarle un vistazo y ayudarme!!

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].